# nosniff causing img src not to work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, helmet.js

I have an Angular 1.5 client, published off of a Node 4,Express 4 server.  I do 99% of my manual testing in IE Edge.  (The rest is in Mocha, Karma, and before delivery, I hit Firefox.)

We recently added this line to our http server, using [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet):

```
//Prevent Mime type sniffing/infering
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
```

**PROBLEM**: The nosniff option broke all of my thumbnails.

In one of my other Angular modules, which is a controller and view component, I have this line:

```
...
<img ng-src="/api/thumbnail/{{title}}"/>
...
```

On my Node/Express server, my `/api/thumbnail/:title/` route looks like this:

```
router.get('/api/thumbnail/:title/',function(req,res){
    ... get file to read from 'title'

    fs.readFile(fileName,function(err,data){
       if ( err ) { ... do error handling ... }
       else { resp.send(data); }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using IE's Network debugger, I noticed that the requests being sent to the server have 'application/octet stream' as the 'Content-Type'.  Maybe because I am sending back an 'image/jpeg', so, I asked myself if that's what is causing the nosniff to kill the response?

In my server code, I have a "DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL" which I send back in the event that 'title' produced no viable thumbnail image for me.  So, before I do a `resp.send(data)`, I did this:

```
const mime = require('mime');
...
resp.setHeader('Content-type',mime.lookup(DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL));
```

And that seemed to fix the **nosniff** issue.

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. That's exactly what I'd have recommended.

Edge was (correctly) sniffing the mimetype as JPEG, so it happened to work. But when you made it respect the mimetype from the server (which was incorrect, `application/octet-stream`), it stopped working.

You did the right thing—send the right `Content-Type`.